# Android - Have two listviews share space if both open, else use all the space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a button with a list view underneath it. The XML looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="@string/button1_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Pressing the button shows or hides a listview underneath it, using this code:

```
private OnClickListener expandOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (listview1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            listview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            listview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
};
```

The result looks like this:

[image: one button, closed]
[image: one button, open]

Now, I have two of these button/listview combinations.

[image: two buttons, both closed]

If the are BOTH open, they should share the space on the screen.

[image: two buttons, both open]

If one or the other is open, they should take up as much of the screen as they can, without pushing the button off the screen.

[image: two buttons, top open]
[image: two buttons, bottom open]

I've tried using weights. I've tried manipulating the height of the linear layout to either 'wrap content' or a specifically calculated pixel value. I've tried to debug through it. It appears to hit all the correct places in the code, but the UI behaves erratically. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing up my entire question, I decided to try a couple of things, and amazingly it works. It's a combination of setting the weights and the heights.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            style="@style/text.body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview2"
            style="@style/text.body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
private OnClickListener expandOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                toggleONEVisibility();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                toggleTWOVisibility();
                break;
        }
    }
};

private void toggleONEVisibility() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam2 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)linearLayout2.getLayoutParams();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam1 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)linearLayout1.getLayoutParams();
    // if ONE is visible
    //    if TWO is visible 
    //       set TWO to 100%
    //    set ONE to GONE
    // else ONE is NOT visible
    //    if TWO is visible
    //       set ONE to 50%
    //       set TWO to 50%
    //    else TWO is NOT visible
    //       set ONE to 100%
    //    set ONE to visible
    if (listview1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        listview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layoutParam1.weight = 0f;
        layoutParam1.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        if (listview2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            layoutParam2.weight = 1f;
            layoutParam2.height = 0;
        }
    } else {
        listview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (listview2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            layoutParam1.weight = 50f;
            layoutParam1.height = 0;
            layoutParam2.weight = 50f;
            layoutParam2.height = 0;
        } else {
            layoutParam1.weight = 1f;
            layoutParam1.height = 0;
            layoutParam2.weight = 0f;
            layoutParam2.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }
    }
    linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutParam1);
    linearLayout2.setLayoutParams(layoutParam2);
}

private void toggleTWOVisibility() {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam2 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)linearLayout2.getLayoutParams();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam1 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)linearLayout1.getLayoutParams();

    // if TWO is visible
    //    if ONE is visible
    //       set ONE to 100%
    //    set TWO to GONE
    // else TWO is NOT visible
    //    if ONE is visible
    //       set ONE to 50%
    //       set TWO to 50%
    //    else ONE is NOT visible
    //       set TWO to 100%
    //    set TWO to visible
    if (listview2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        listview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layoutParam2.weight = 0f;
        layoutParam2.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        if (listview1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            layoutParam1.weight = 1f;
            layoutParam1.height = 0;
        }
    } else {
        listview2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (listview1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            layoutParam1.weight = 50f; 
            layoutParam1.height = 0;
            layoutParam2.weight = 50f;
            layoutParam2.height = 0;
        } else {
            layoutParam1.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            layoutParam1.weight = 0f;
            layoutParam2.weight = 1f;
            layoutParam2.height = 0;
        }
    }

    linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(layoutParam1);
    linearLayout2.setLayoutParams(layoutParam2);
}
```